I can't manage to make PDO works in PHP
i've used PDO without problems (we did installed it with our teacher, as i remember we just had to uncomment the extensions line) and two days ago i tried to reinstall the whole lamp stack (cause i don't use apache yet and was willing to learn), and by doing so it seems that i'v broke everything relative to PDO..
i'm on php 8.1, i run my back server on port localhost:7000/
i've uncommented these lines :
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
php
on all the copy i could find of php.ini across my system (and elso in here /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini)
i even did this echo :
 <?php
if (class_exists('PDO')) {
    echo "PDO is installed and available.";
} else {
    echo "PDO is not installed or unavailable.";
}
phpinfo();
?>

wich returned :
PDO is installed and available.phpinfo()
PHP Version => 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14

and also when i grep php and pdo i SEE IT THERE:
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
filter
hash
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Reflection
session
sodium
SPL
standard
zlib

[Zend Modules]

So where should i look, i've tried to reinstall the whole lamp stack but it don't seems to change anything.. tell me if you need more infos to help thxs a lot to everyone :')
i've look for every a->z intalling/enabling tuto i could find, and i ended up with this message error:
[Tue Apr  9 16:49:40 2024] 127.0.0.1:54236 [200]: OPTIONS /Controller/ControllerLogin.php - Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /home/sam/my_social_network/Model/ModelLogin.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sam/my_social_network/Model/ModelLogin.php(21): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '')
#1 /home/sam/my_social_network/Controller/ControllerLogin.php(15): LoginUser->__construct(NULL, NULL)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/sam/my_social_network/Model/ModelLogin.php on line 21


PDO is a database abstraction. Beside PDO you need to install a certain driver in order to communicate with certain DBMS. So most likely you need to uncomment pdo_mysql as well. Or, rather, just apt install php-mysql

so here's the uncommented part of php.ini:
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
is it enough ??  (cause it still not working)
and as for the apt install here's the result telling me that i'm already up to date :
php-mysql is already the newest version (2:8.1+92ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

run phpinfo and look for the Loaded configuration file. It will tell you which PHP is used for web requests. then you need to install php-mysql for this php

already tried, but i've finally found!
it was this line that was missing
extension = mysqlnd.so
so the block look like this :
extension = mysqlnd.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
i'va also had to create a mysql user other than root without password (wich worked previously but meh) and set a password :) thanks a lot !!
